# Understanding the working of Cerebrata Azure Diagnostics Manager

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I have created a REST service which is hosted on azure and to diagnose it, I have used Cerebrata Azure Diagnostic Manager for Performance Counter.

The Cerebrata Azure Diagnostic Manager is working fine giving the Performance Counter output but I am unable to understand the Diagnostic data especially in the performance chart that for what x and y axis are referred to. How much the values in chart exceed.

Please do help me in Understanding the Cerebrata Azure Diagnostic Manager's diagnostic data. I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question about the tool? Or about the underlying data?

In general, the x-axis is for time and the y-axis gives the values of the performance counters.

Does their demo video help at all - http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/Details.aspx?t1=0&t2=1

Maybe post a screenshot of something you have specific questions about?